# what's the difference on dealing char between where statement and if statement in SAS 9.4M6

Tags: if-statement, sas, where-clause

Recently, I happen to find an interesting thing:

```
data test;
    set sashelp.class;
    if _N_ in (2 3 5 7) then name = '';
run;

data test;
    set ;
    where name;
run;
```

The result is: **data Test has 15 observations.**

I use SAS 9.4M6 for over a year and don't remember that `where` statment can deal with char type variable just like boolean type variable. I strightly change `where` to `if` and it leads the results: **name is not a numeric variable and data Test has 0 observation.**

So here is my two questions:
1. Is `where name;` another way of `where name is not missing`? if not, what happens when submit`where name`?
2. When did this kind of code(*`where <variable>;`*) start be allowed in SAS?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a test for non empty values.  I have used it for years, mainly when interactively browsing a dataset.  I suspect it has been there since SAS introduced the WHERE statement, or at least since they re-factored it to use the same syntax as SQL WHERE clauses.

WHERE statements use PROC SQL style syntax (use of LIKE no use of variable lists) but IF statements use normal SAS syntax.

So if you used

```
if name ;
```

in your data step then you would see notes about SAS trying to convert the character variable NAME into a number that it can evaluate as FALSE (zero of missing) or TRUE (any other value).  Since the names in SASHELP.CLASS cannot be converted to numbers then all of them will be treated as FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting find! I also have not noticed this. I tried this on both 9.4M4 and 9.4M5 and received the same results. This may be something added even earlier than that. I see no documentation on it as well. From testing, here is what I am able to see:

1. `where` statements can automatically convert characters such as as `if name` to boolean statements
2. `if` statements do not automatically convert characters to boolean and require the user to explicitly state the character you are trying to exclude, e.g.

Code:

```
data want;
    set test ;
    if(NOT missing(name));
run;
```

I cannot tell when this was added, but it is earlier than versions I have access to. Your test code would be a great quiz question!